# why inotifywait command shows multiple pids?

Tags: linux, inotifywait

i created one bash script named "quicktest.sh".  the task of this script is to set inotifywait on Data folder from all users home directory.
the code of quicktest.sh is down below:

```
function inotify_data() 
{  
user="$1"  
if [ -d /home/$user/Data ];  
then    
while read -r  path action file; do          
       echo "The file '$file' created"  
       chmod 0777 -R /home/$user/Data  
done < <(exec inotifywait -m -r /home/$user/Data  -e moved_to -e create -e modify)  
fi  
} 

cd /home/  
ls >/tmp/.grp   
i=1  
n=`wc -l </tmp/.grp`   
while [ "$i" -le "$n" ]  
do   
     user=`awk "NR==$i" /tmp/.grp`  
     echo "setting watch on $user Data Folder."  
     inotify_data "$user" &  
     i=$((i+1))  
done
```

i have 2 users in my machine,
after running this script, i run "ps -ef | grep -i quicktest.sh" , then it will shows two process of this file.